# Django Factory boy usage

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, factory-boy

Given the following models:

```
from django.db import models


class A(models.Model):
    foo = models.TextField()


# B inherits from A, it's not abstract so it should 
# create a table with a foreign key relationship
class B(A):
    bar = models.TextField()
```

And the following test with `DjangoModel` factories:

```
from django.test import TestCase
import factory
from factory.django import DjangoModelFactory
from .models import A, B


class AFactory(DjangoModelFactory):
    foo = factory.Faker('name')

    class Meta:
        model = A


class BFactory(DjangoModelFactory):
    bar = factory.Faker('name')

    class Meta:
        model = B


class BTestCase(TestCase):
    def test_1(self):
        b = BFactory()
        print(b.foo)  # prints ''
```

How can I get `b.foo` to refer to an actual `A` entity with a valid `foo` attribute?

At the moment `b.foo` just returns an empty string. But if I create an `A` entity using the `AFactory`, the entity has a properly populated `foo` field:

```
>>> a_ent = AFactory()
>>> a_ent.foo
'Nicholas Williams'
```

I would like BFactory to create an `A` entity for me that `b` can refer to.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to extend BFactory from AFactory:

```
class AFactory(DjangoModelFactory):
    foo = factory.Faker('name')

    class Meta:
        model = A


class BFactory(AFactory):
    bar = factory.Faker('name')

    class Meta:
        model = B

b = BFactory()
print(b.foo)  # Robert Rogers
print(b.bar)  # Maria Clark
```

BFactory is used to create the database records through the B model, so for this to work you need to define the factory fields on the BFactory. This can be easily done with the inheritance above.